# Asp.net/C# append header error on mutliple email downloads

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have an asp.net/c# application that has a function where the user triggers whatever it is and an email will be downloaded. That works perfectly fine if there is one email that is being triggered/downloaded. However if there are multiple emails i am getting a "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent" error. I have messed around and did a bit of google fu but nothing seems to be working.

It errors out on the 'Response.AddHeaders' line AFTER the first email has been generated.

```
public void EmailDownload(string toAddress, string ccAddress, string subject, string body, string downloadName)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
        var mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.Body = body;
            //message.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailAddress);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccAddress))
            {
                message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccAddress));
            }
            //message.From = new MailAddress("noreply@company.com");
            message.From = new MailAddress(emailAddress);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Headers.Add("X-Unsent", "1");
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            // Get reflection info for MailWriter contructor
            var mailWriterContructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);

            // Construct MailWriter object with our FileStream
            var mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { stream });

            // Get reflection info for Send() method on MailMessage
            var sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            // Call method passing in MailWriter
            sendMethod.Invoke(message, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true, true }, null);

            // Finally get reflection info for Close() method on our MailWriter
            var closeMethod = mailWriter.GetType().GetMethod("Close", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            // Call close method
            closeMethod.Invoke(mailWriter, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new object[] { }, null);

            byte[] data = stream.ToArray();
            stream.Close();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=" + downloadName + ".eml");
            Response.BinaryWrite(data);
            //Response.End();
            Response.Flush();
            Response.SuppressContent = true;
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one page response to send a file. Once you do that, all code terminates.

I don't believe you can send/have multiple page response(s) in one shot.  You create a response and send it - your code now terminates at that point in time.

This suggest if you want user to get/grab/have multiple files, then you need a UI say like this:

[image]

The markup is a gridview, and we have a simple asp.net button. So this:

markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="File Name" HeaderText="File"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="File Size" HeaderText="Size" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdDownLoad" runat="server" Text="Download" cssclass="btn"
                            OnClick="cmdDownLoad_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And the button code:

```
   protected void cmdDownLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow gRow = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        string sFileOnly = gRow.Cells[0].Text;
        string sFile = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Animals/" + sFileOnly);

        string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(sFile);

        Response.ContentType = sMineType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileOnly);
        Response.TransmitFile(sFile);
        Response.End();

    }
```

In fact, if I put code after response end, say like this:

```
    Response.ContentType = sMineType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileOnly);
        Response.TransmitFile(sFile);
        Response.End();

        Debug.Print("code runs after above");
```

The debug print code NEVER runs, since I had to use a response.end to send the one file. Once you do that - ALL code terminates.

So, you have to display/provide a list of emails, and give the user a button or some such to download each file. You could thus create a table in code, or even a ListItem, and send that to the grid.

And give that each button click is a post-back, then you have to persist the list of emails in viewstate or session for display in that grid. You could build up a listiem struct, pass that to the grid, and thus the GV will persist the list for you (see how I grabbed the file from the GV in above).

Comment: Appreciate the in-depth response! I will work on implementing this and let you know! Thank you!